# Logging in Server Project's Controller for Blazor Web Assembly Solution Not displayed

Tags: logging, controller, blazor, webassembly, webapi

I am trying to figure out logging for a Blazor Web Assembly solution and am struggling.

To be clear.  I have a Blazor Web Assembly solution and I am seeing this issue in its Server project.

I placed the following as the first line in the Put of my WebAPI controller in my server project, no if statement, just an attempt at my first log:

logger.LogCritical($"In Put");

I have placed a break point on this statement and can see that I am executing the statement, however, it has no impact.  I see no corresponding message in the console.

Completely new to logging, so I'm not even sure what information to provide.

I am:

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, including examples of configuring the server project in the Blazor Web Assembly solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I placed the following in the Blazor Component's Update function:

Logger.LogWarning("Temporary:  About to Save");

    await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/CaptureType", CaptureType_Singleton, JsonHelper.SerializationOptions);
    
    Logger.LogWarning("Temporary:  Completed Save");

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I placed the following in the Blazor Component's Update function:

Logger.LogWarning("Temporary:  About to Save");

    await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/CaptureType", CaptureType_Singleton, JsonHelper.SerializationOptions);
    
    Logger.LogWarning("Temporary:  Completed Save");


And in the called WebApi I have placed this [which I can see is executed via a breakpoint]:


logger.LogError($"Post Error in Capture Type Controller");


Reviewing the console, the Blazor component's warnings are logged, but the Error logged via the Web Api aren't.

Comment: I think this error would show up in the Event Viewer

Comment: Clamchoda,  Thank you.  I did find it there.